# Is there a way to Insert the Output of an Output

Tags: sql

I am trying to find a way to take the output of data that has already been output and then re-insert (kind of an output/insert x 2)

Here's the code I would use, can someone please let me know if there is a way around this?

```
INSERT INTO table1
(
Field1, Field2, Field3
)
OUTPUT
inserted.values1, inserted.values2, insertedvalues3
INTO table2
(
Field1, Field2, Field3
)

OUTPUT 
inserted.values1, inserted.values2, insertedvalues3 -- from table2
INTO table3
(
Field1, Field2, Field3
)

SELECT values1, values2, values3
FROM MasterTable
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using (which I would guess is some version of SQL Server).

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary table and then do - OUTPUT INTO - into that temporary table.
Then insert the values into table2 and table3 by selecting from the temporary table.

```
CREATE TABLE table1(Field1 INT, Field2 int, Field3 int);
CREATE TABLE table2(Field1 INT, Field2 int, Field3 int);
CREATE TABLE table3(Field1 INT, Field2 int, Field3 int);

-- Our temporary table
CREATE TABLE #results(Field1 INT, Field2 int, Field3 int);

INSERT INTO table1(Field1, Field2, Field3)
    OUTPUT inserted.Field1, inserted.Field2, inserted.Field3
    INTO #results(Field1, Field2, Field3)
VALUES (1, 2, 3)

-- Now insert the "inserted" values into the two target tables
INSERT INTO dbo.table2( Field1, Field2, Field3 )
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM #results;

INSERT INTO dbo.table3( Field1, Field2, Field3 )
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM #results;
```